# can I not mention that I have will complete a PhD degree while applying for another one in another country

Tags: phd

I am a second-year Ph.D. student/ RA from a university in country A. I had no problem with my laboratory or supervisor; however, as I could not speak the country language and was not able to find a post-doc position due to COVID, I applied for another Ph.D. positions in the same field in an English speaking country (B) where I can immigrate and settle. In the application form for the universities and during my interviews I mentioned that I am a Research assistant, omitting the fact that I am a Ph.D. candidate. Also, my supervisors mentioned that I am RA in their recommendation letters understating the fact that I want to go to an English-speaking country. The problem is that due to my successful publications our department from country A decided to grant me the Ph.D. degree at the end of this year.
I read some posts that mentioned that omitting your academic records is the same as falsifying them. I am afraid if I go to country B without mentioning that I was in fact a Ph.D. candidate and RA and get in huge trouble, so what should I do?
Is it be unethical if I omit this fact that I would have a Ph.D., refer it to RA and start the second Ph.D. in the same field in country B, or should I contact the prospective professors from country B and tell him/her that I did a mistake in my application?

Comment: Are the two PhDs in the same field? Also, did the award o the first one come after the application for the second? Ethically you need to inform them somehow.

Comment: I'm not clear on your motivation for all this.  If your current department is awarding you your PhD, couldn't you take that and move to another country?  Why start over in a new program in the same field?

Comment: @Buffy yes they are in the same field and yes I have already applied for the second university (that time I did not think that I am going to be granted the PhD in just two years) and will get the PhD in the upcoming months.

Comment: @jeff To be honest, I applied because I was not ready to start to career cause I got both of my master and PhD faster than expected, so I wanted to expand my knowledge on different fields of the same subject. Also as mentioned I was to immigrate to country B and amid covid I could not find a job there so I applied for PhD. And while I have applied for the same school research subject and proposal is completely different.

Comment: I see, is a post-doc an option?

Comment: Beware how immigration officials may look on someone seeking a degree as a path to immigration rather than for education.

Comment: @jeff I did not consult with the prospective professors about this, but in their website they mentioned that they have fund for graduate students and nothing mentioned about post doc. Also I do not have too much publications (5-6), experience to do the post-doc

Comment: I voted to close because the answer was in the question: "I read some posts that mentioned that omitting your academic records is the same as falsifying them."

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104671/can-i-legally-omit-the-fact-i-hold-a-ph-d-degree

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105551/is-it-ethical-to-omit-the-phd-credential-from-my-resume

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/can-i-hide-my-bachelor-and-master-degrees-in-cv-when-i-apply-for-a-phd-position

Answer (score 1):

The comment of Jeff is worth considering. Do you really need a second doctorate to migrate.

But, under the circumstances, send a message to the new university stating that since your application, you were awarded a PhD, but, assuming you want to, that you still want to continue your application and enter the new program. Stress that the research proposal will be different if accepted.

Hiding the recent degree could come back to harm you.

Answer (score -3):

Does country B automatically recognize academic degrees from country A? If yes, I'm afraid you have to mention your PhD. If no, technically for them in country B you are (academically) nobody.